# asp.net mvc controller method that returns jpeg given parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to create a jpeg on the fly given some data from a database. The data is an array containing values which should be translated into a colour.

A asp.net mvc controller method should return a jpeg on the fly given one parameter.

This should be fairly straight forward. Could someone please point me to some existing code?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are probably looking for this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this in pure mvc you can do this

[Extending MVC: Returning an Image from a Controller Action](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/13/extending-mvc-returning-an-image-from-a-controller-action.aspx)

Another way is to create a HttpHandler that does that for you

[HTTP Handlers for Images in ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/desaijm/HTTPHandlersForImages11152005062705AM/HTTPHandlersForImages.aspx)

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of possible options that may help you get started:
I think you will porbably need an handler and then call the handler from your controller.

[SO POst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771585/ashx-file-creating-images-in-mvc-asp-net)
[Bob Cravens post](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/09/image-handler-in-asp-net-webforms-and-mvc/)
[Scott Hansleman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETFuturesGeneratingDynamicImagesWithHttpHandlersGetsEasier.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on msdn on [How to: Encode and Decode a JPEG Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970689.aspx).

Doing that in MVC3 is pretty similar, you just need a action in your **controller** like this:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ImageResult GetImage(int whatever)
    {
        stream imageStream = yourJpgFactory.GetImage(whatever)
        return (imageStream)
    }
}
```

and in your **view**

```
 <img src="YourController/GetImage?whatever=42" />
```